# cx_freeze not compiling on Python3.4.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm having trouble compiling cx_freeze on Python3.4.0 .
I'm running Xubuntu14.04 64 bit, and using pip3 to install. I seem to get the same issue compiling cx_freeze directly, so I don't think pip3 is at fault.

Pip3 produces a log file when it fails, and I have uploaded that log here: http://bpaste.net/raw/lgbIMFeotpYJlqJPlJ4D/

I've tried upgrading to Python 3.4.1, though that didn't help.
I've heard from others than cx_freeze compiles fine on Python2, but that doesn't directly help me.

And yes, Python3-dev is definitely installed.

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu change something in Python that prevents cx_Freeze from compiling. We haven't worked out how to fix it, but there's a workaround described in [this bug report](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/32/cant-compile-cx_freeze-in-ubuntu-1304).

Comment: @ThomasK Thanks for that. That looks very much like the issue I'm having, and I'll try the workaround ASAP.